# Multiple Instances of Source Code Editors

Tags: javascript, performance, codemirror, code-editor

I'm looking for a lightweight source code editor. I need multiple instances of it running on one page, up to 15. I've been working with Codemirror and a custom Dust JS mode for it. The performance of running over 10 of these codemirror instances is not good. Anyone have ideas for alternatives to codemirror and ace that are especially lightweight? Or ideas on how to increase performance of codemirror instances?

Comment: Did you try SublimeText ?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the performance not being good? Are you talking about startup time, responsiveness, or something else? How much code is in these editors?

Comment: @Marijn I'm also running multiple instances (can be hundreds) of editor. I have big table and each cell can contain code. Each CodeEditor takes about 15-40ms to load and then 20ms to refresh the interface. This is not a lot individually, but it adds up quite fast. Each editor only has a single line of code to color. I'll probably use the coloring only when user is actually editing a cell. Once they are loaded, it is pretty fast though.